# How to disable whole app if the internet connection lost?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to disable whole app and make screen like this:

[image]

that user won't be able interact with my app. How can I do it?

I've tried `view.userInteractionEnabled = false` but this does not make my screen semi-transparent, as in the image showed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a view on window to disable all functionalities and make use of Reachability notification so that when internet connection comes back user must be able to use your app

Comment: When it comes to UI/UX you shouldn't disable the current screen, you should push a new view controller which will tell the user that the internet connection is lost - inside this view controller you should add a 'Try again' button and maybe 'Close App' button.
A good design will be to create a base class which all view controllers will inherit and the error implementation will be there.
Also, as @Leena mentioned you should use the reachability notification - you have a lot of wrappers in github for that. Good luck.

Comment: You should use the built in UIVisualEffectView methods to blur the background.

I'm curious though, you had a perfectly good TableView question where the cells were doubling, tripling, based on section count.  But you went ahead and deleted it.  How come?

Answer (score 0):

Things don't magically change transparency.

First you need to identify that you Internet connection is down. This can be done with a class called reachability.

Then you need to take all the actions you want to take including making the button more transparent and disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with your uiimageview to window at center and
set color for view is clear , set

> userInteractionEnabled = false

Detect internet connection. if yes add view to window, and

> removefromsuperview

when lost